# Firebase function not responding to Pub/Sub message

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-functions

I feel like I might be missing something simple, but I can't get a Cloud Function for Firebase to respond to a Pub/Sub published message. It works fine when I deploy using cloud and opt for the Admin SDK for Node.js, but Auth is tricky; it works for the first write and then it fails to authenticate.

With the release of Cloud Function for Firebase, I decided to try again. My function code is as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

function pushOrderToFirebase(completedOrder) {

  admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

  //setters and getters for the message that will be pushed to firebase

  admin.database().ref('/orders').push({
    name: curDriverName,
    recipient: recipient,
    address: address,
    details: details,
    isDelivered: isDelivered,
    failureReason: failureReason,
    time: formattedTime
  }).then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot);
  });
}
exports.firebasePusherAlpha = functions.pubsub.topic('test-topic').onPublish(event => {
  const pubSubMessage = event.data;

  let parsedMessage = null;
  try {
    parsedMessage = pubSubMessage.json;
    console.log(parsedMessage);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('PubSub message was not JSON', e);
  }
  pushOrderToFirebase(parsedMessage);
  callback();
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't get called when I publish a pubsub message.

Comment: any logs ? any errors ? how did you deploy your function ?

Comment: Cloud Functions for Firebase are promise based, make sure you're returning a Promise. In this example, pushOrderToFirebase should return the ref(..).push(...) and firebasePusherAlpha should return pushOrderToFirebase. Execution will not be guaranteed without an unresolved promise.